# SQL timeout when inserting data into temp table in custom application

Tags: sql, sql-server, timeoutexception

- I have a console .net application that reads a one-line single value
  data from a file.
- The application is having SQL timeout issues for few days last month for which I am working to find root cause.
- The logic in app uses single value to pull data from base tables based on column values higher than single data from file.
- The data pulled from base tables joins are dumped into two temporary tables present in script attached.
- The two temp tables is joined with base tables and data from joins is dumped into one final  temp table(AccMatters) from where we update base / permanent tables after checking certain business logic for charge code validation(time charged by employee / users working on certain matters for company carry charge code to be used for charging time).
- Attached SQL code that gave timeout issue. The temporary table AccMatters is having issue during insertion. Comments are available in SQL code for giving information on code.
- The script contain code till dumping to last temp table as timeout issue occurred at that point when checking logs of .net console application which has the SQL statements embedded in it.
- The issue occurred for three days last month and volume of records inserted into last temporary tables was 800+ rows on those days when timeout issue occurred.
- When executing in production environment, the script takes few minutes that is very much less than timeout of 20 minutes set in the application.
- The custom app at last updates file containing single data with new data from base table that is greater than that value and file data is again used in next run of custom application.

Any help on possible SQL server code inconsistencies that can be identified in attached script will be helpful in identifying root cause of issue for days when issue was reported by customer.

Comment: did you tried using global temp table instead, ## or is there any reason why u cant use it

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. We dont have any reason not to use ##. But, having said so, we also would like to mention that the code was written earlier by another team but only maintained / checking for issue by our team now. Moreover, issue occurred only for 3 days last month. The issue was also not simulatable with data in production for the days when it happened but we cannot close case with customer without root cause.

Comment: Customer is asking only root cause and they dont require fix now

Comment: Have tried very much lot trying to simulate and also explored in other forums but failed and not having any clue on why timeout happened, Any help will be really appreciated please!!

Comment: Can you possibly add script pls ?

Comment: Looking into suggestions provided in post for checking diagnostics and will check. Some restrictions in posting code

Comment: Thanks once again for fast responses / questions. My request based on diagnostics recommendations in post earlier for tempdb and log files is being reviewed in my team post which I will get the information from Production support team asap. Once I get some clarity on possible cause after analysis of information, I will surely add further comments. Thanks for help provided. It is a fantastic experience considering I joined StackOverflow today!!

Answer (score 1):

If it is the case, you need to run few diagnostic scripts to find out whats happening in server.

1) reader/writer conflict

```
 DBCC OpenTran (dbname)
```

2) Check for the tempdb latency and the log file growth of Tempdb

3) Any blocked sessions/processess

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.sysprocesses WHERE blocked <> 0;
SELECT * FROM dbo.sysprocesses WHERE spid IN (SELECT blocked FROM 
              dbo.sysprocesses where blocked <> 0)
```

4) Check if that proc falls under high impact query on disk/latency

```
SELECT TOP 10 t.TEXT AS 'SQL Text'
    ,st.execution_count
    ,ISNULL(st.total_elapsed_time / st.execution_count, 0) AS 'AVG Excecution Time'
    ,st.total_worker_time / st.execution_count AS 'AVG Worker Time'
    ,st.total_worker_time
    ,st.max_logical_reads
    ,st.max_logical_writes
    ,st.creation_time
    ,ISNULL(st.execution_count / DATEDIFF(second, st.creation_time, 
    getdate()), 0) AS 'Calls Per Second'
    FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats st
   CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(st.sql_handle) t
   ORDER BY creation_time desc
```

5) Use activity Monitor to check if response time of TempDB is higher

I would really like to look at perfmon counters to start with, check for the abnormal growth of temp db log file. I would say create another similar proc and name it differently with global temp tables. Debugging would give you enough idea of whats happening in the server.